# Creating a Device Tree Overlay for Raspberry Pi Camera on RockPi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, device-tree

I want to use a raspberry pi global shutter camera (imx296) with a rock pi 4. The problem is that the rock pi only has overlays for the standard pi camera (imx219).
I was able to find the dts files for imx219 on both rockpi and raspberry pi as well as the imx296 dts file for raspberry pi.

Unfortunately I have no experience with creating and compiling device tree overlays. With the information I was able to find, is it possible to create a dts file for the imx296 on rock pi? If it is possible how much effort would it be/would it be worth looking into?
Is there an easier solution? My current workaround is using a raspberry pi zero in addition to the rock pi but I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: The rPi specialists are hanging out on [raspberrypi.se] . Readers here will help you fix your code, once you have some. Good luck.